# how to show the category description in breadcrumb page in magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I want to show category name and description in breadcrumb page i.e.,in `app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml` rather than in `app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/page/catalog/category/view.phtml`

i managed to show category name but unable to show category description.
i added some code in breadcrumbs.phtml

```
<?php if($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)): ?>
<div>
    <ul class="bradecom">
        <?php foreach($crumbs as $_crumbName=>$_crumbInfo): ?>
            <li class="<?php echo $_crumbName ?>">
            <?php if($_crumbInfo['link']): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $_crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['title']) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></a>
            <?php elseif($_crumbInfo['last']): ?>
            &nbsp;
               <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if(!$_crumbInfo['last']): ?>                
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

    <ul><li class="<?php echo $_crumbName ?>"><h1> <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></h1></li> </ul>
```

if anyone knows how to show category description here,then please help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Price,you can get description of  `current category Using Registry function and Controller Name` any where of Category...

$category=$this->getRequest()->getControllerName();

```
if(Mage::registry('current_category')&& ($category == 'category')){
echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getDescription();
}
```

Comment: just  remove strtolower($action->getFullActionName() condition

Comment: one problem is there i want to show description only in product listing page not in every page.now it is coming in product view page also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57143/discussion-between-prince-kumar-and-amit-bera).

Comment: Amit please tell me if you have any idea its urgent

Comment: catalog_category_view to catalog_product_view,if register have current catgeory then you can get description..

Comment: I just want a condition that category description will show in listing page not in product view page or any other pages.is it possible?